# How to control multiple GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, gameobject

I'm currently in the process of making my first bigger game in Unity 2D with C#, and I have a problem. I have already searched a lot for answers, but I haven't been successful.

My problem is, that I want to make multiple doors that the player can open individually (there will be around 40 doors). I think I will deactivate the closed door GameObject and activate the open door GameObject.

And I feel like there must be a better way of controlling multiple GameObjects than to drag and drop to separate variables and make an if statement for each door in the script.

E.g:

```
if (door4 gets opened) {
door4Closed.setActive(false); 
door4Open.setActive(true);
}
```

It has been a problem for some time, and making the doors is just one of the times I've run into this type of problem.

I have played around with GameObjects arrays and .find, but I still feel like there must be af better way.

So I would like help to:

1: Deactivate and activate a specific GameObject among many.

2: Maybe even making a better door system.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

Edited after OP provided more information.

If all doors can be freely opened without any checks, the easiest way would be creating a script that inherits MonoBehaviour and assign it to a prefab that you use to create the doors.

If the doors are already there, you can select all of them at once on the hierarchy and add this door component to all of them at the same time.

To avoid the need of dragging and droping every single variable of the door script manually you can do it on the door script itself.

This is a script assumes that:

1. The Collider of the door is in the same gameobject as this.
2. The Colllider has the "IsTrigger" **ticked**.
3. The player's gameobject that contains the collider is tagged as "Player" (change the tag on the script if it's not that one).

The script contains two different ways of assigning those variables in the editor.
1: Using the Reset() event function, which is called whenever you add this script inside the editor or when you click "Reset" on the context menu.

2 (My preferred): Using the OnValidate() event function, which is called whenever you load the gameobject on the editor or when you edit any value on the inspector.

Futhermore, this is a suggestion of implementation, you should customize your own based on your specific needs.

```
public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _isOpen;

    private bool IsOpenHandler
    {
        get => _isOpen;
        set
        {
            if (_isOpen && !value)
                ExecuteCloseAnimation();
            else if (!_isOpen && value)
                ExecuteOpenAnimation();
            
            _isOpen = value;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            IsOpenHandler = !IsOpenHandler;
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
```

#if UNITY_EDITOR // we can't let this compile on game builds because the UnityEditor namespace does not exist on builds (which we are using bellow)

```
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (animator != null) // if we already have the animator we don't need to do anything
            return;

        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (animator == null) // if we fail to get the animator we log a warning to let you know
            Debug.LogWarning($"Could not find animator on {gameobject.name}!", this); 
        else
            UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this); //this sets this gameobject as dirty and is needed to force the Editor to save the changes we made when you click "Save"
    }
```

#endif
}

Comment: And then I have to call the function from a different script? And how can I give the player the ability to close the door again? I have also specified the question a bit, because I realized it was a bit unclear.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to call the function from a different script, it depends on how the player interacts with door (which is the input/action needed to open the door).

To give the ability to the player to close the door you should declare a method inside the door script that handles the closing (in a similar maner as the openning one).

Comment: If the player's collider hits a collider around the door, and the player presses "e", the door needs to open/close.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to fullfill that requirement

Answer (score -1):

What language are you using? The following is a general template you can use, as long as it is object-oriented.

Create a Door class. Make each door an object of class door. Define class door to have an attribute that keeps track of state such as `opened = false`. It's also good practice to make getter and setter methods:

```
function open() {
   opened = true;
}
```

This way, you can easily change the state of doors.

```
Door d = new Door();
d.open();
```

You could keep track of the doors using an ArrayList if you wanted.

```
ArrayList<Door> doors = new ArrayList<Door>();
doors.add(d);
doors.get(0).close();
```

Comment: As it says c# … your code is not c#…

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry I forgot to add that I'm using C#, and I'm making my game in Unity. Could you make an example in c#? :D